# Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: created in vue 3 life cycle hook

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, lifecycle-hook, vuejs3-composition-api

I want to run a event before content load. I do it on Vue 3 option API wiht created() lifecycle hook but Now, I do it with Vue 3 Composition API.

Code:

```
<script setup>
import { created } from "vue";

const initDark = created(() => {
  console.log("init");
});

</script>
```

When I use it then show a console error.

[image]

How can i solve this.

I try below code but it didn't work as expected and it generate a console error.

```
<script setup>
import { created } from "vue";

const initDark = created(() => {
  console.log("init");
});

</script>
```

Comment: Composition Api does not have beforeCreated or Created hooks. they all run when the script runs for the first time. no need to add any hook initializing here.

Comment: What's initDark? A hook isn't supposed to return anything, even if it existed

Comment: I need to run some code when running my app in Vue 3. How can I do it? @PouyaM

Comment: @MonzurAlam Create an init function and put you code there and call you function! you can also put your logic code in a seperate file with '.vue' extention and export them so you can access them anywhere you want and run them.

Answer (score 2):

No, [Vue3 Composition API does not include a lifecycle method named `created`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-lifecycle.html). This is because `created` has been replaced with `setup`.

You can write `console.log("init");` at the top-level.

tip: if you want to include a lifecycle hook like `mounted`, import `onMounted` instead of `mounted`:

```
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
onMounted(() => {
  console.log('This is onMounted hook');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @kaikai for your answer. 
I used the onMounted hook but there is some issue, So I need to run the code on the first load.

Comment: `setup`, the top-level of `<script setup>`, is the hook you need if you don't want ssr :)